# mention user on chatter throwing error (method removed after version 31.0)

Tags: chatter, user, chatter-feed

My class version is 40.0 .

i have created trigger on task object when task is open its post on chatter and tag a user but the error is  **Error: Compile Error: Method was removed after version 31.0: postFeedItem**

```
  ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedItem(null, ConnectApi.FeedType.UserProfile, tery.userId, input, null);
```

Answer (score 4):

As per these [Summer 14 release](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer14/release-notes/rn_connect_in_apex_classes.htm):

> The `getFeedItem` and `postFeedItem` methods are still supported, but to future-proof your applications, use the `getFeedElement` and `postFeedElement` methods. For example, as of API version 31.0, the only feed element types are feed item and bundle, but that could change in future releases.

So it's better to use `postFeedElement()` method.

`postFeedElement(String, String, ConnectApi.FeedElementType, String)` — Posts a feed element with plain text from the context user.